# Implementing pdf.js in android to read from sd card

Tags: javascript, android, html, pdf, pdf.js

I'm trying to implement a pdf viewer for my android app which displays different pdf files which are present in the SD card.

I am thinking of using the pdf.js library.I used the code sample as posted here: https://bitbucket.org/butelo/pdfviewer/

However, the library takes the pdf url in the javascript file which is relative address to the folder to which it belongs (/assets/pdfviewer).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = '../compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';
</script>
```

How can I redirect it to use a pdf present in a folder in the sdcard ?

Also the filenames of the pdfs are not fixed and I need to change them in the program as per requirement.

Update --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I updated the java code like this:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/data/test.pdf");
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/index.html?file=" + path);
```

In the pdffile.js, I modified the following:

From:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = '../compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';
</script>
```

To:

```
var url = getURLParameter('file');


function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null}
```

The above javascript code extracts the 'file' parameter from the URL of the 'index.html'

Still does not work. The webview 'chromium' in logcat shows:

```
I/chromium(1353): [INFO:CONSOLE(106)] "Warning: Unhandled rejection: 
Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "file:///storage/sdcard0/data/test.pdf".", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/pdf.js (106)"
```

This seems to be cross server issue. So how can I modify the pdf.js code to read local files without server ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I faced with the same issue

Comment: Yes, see my question details as well as my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the issue. The app was missing `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions.

The code can be found at: https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js
Its Apache V2 license, so feel free to use in your app.

Comment: Just add @SuppressLint("NewApi") to your onCreate method. The code works fine in API 10 and above.

Comment: i have added @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "SetJavaScriptEnabled", "SdCardPath" }) above class

Comment: Still does not work, webview always shows Page: /
Logcat output: 
E/AndroidProtocolHandler: Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/THE_FILE
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Uncaught (in promise) Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of null", source: file:///android_asset/pdfviewer/index.html?file=/storage/emulated/0/data/test.pdf (0)
Any help is highly appreciated, thank you.