# How can I display an inline PDF Document on an Android Device?

Tags: android, html, cordova, pdf, phonegap-plugins

I need to display a PDF document on an HTML page, not on a seperate page display only the PDF.

Basically a user will click a button, that button will take them to a new page that has a Header Section, Footer Section, and a PDF in between these two sections.

My first thought as an iFrame. It worked beautifully on my browser. But as soon as I ported the application over to the android device, I realized that the android device doesn't even display the PDF. It's just blank space where the PDF should be....

Is there anyway for me to display the PDF as I need it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library: [PDF.js](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) or this fork: [Android-pdf.js](https://github.com/pauldmps/Android-pdf.js/tree/master). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291980/implementing-pdf-js-in-android-to-read-from-sd-card) you have examples of use

Answer (score 0):

download the library or use mavaen url and import in your project  from
https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

and simply place below xml code in your layout

```
 <RelativeLayout>
    <yourheader id="header" 
    alignParentTop="true"/>

        <com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
                android:id="@+id/pdfview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                below="id/header"
                above="id/footer"/>

         <yourFooter id="footer"
          alignparentBottom="true"/>
    <RelativeLayout>
```

and below code in your activity onCreate

```
pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
    .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
    .defaultPage(1)
    .showMinimap(false)
    .enableSwipe(true)
    .onDraw(onDrawListener)
    .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
    .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
    .load();
```

it will do the rest.

All credit goes to https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

pages is optional, it allows you to filter and order the pages of the PDF as you need

onDraw is also optional, and allows you to draw something on a provided canvas, above the current page